# List of all android apps on google play

Tags: android

Is there an API/service that can provide an up to date snapshot of all Android apps on google play marketplace?

thank you

Comment: It's 90% live wallpapers. You have been warned.

Comment: I am sorry Keyser. I do not understand your comment. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official Google Play API that provides data like this. If you want to index Google Play, you will have to crawl it manually.

If you want to open up lists in your app, then you can use the URLs given [here](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html).

Answer (score 1):

Check with the [Google Play Terms of Service](https://www.google.com/mobile/android/market-tos.html) first:

> 3.3 You agree not to access (or attempt to access) Google Play by any means other than through the interface that is provided by Google, unless you have been specifically allowed to do so in a separate agreement with Google. You specifically agree not to access (or attempt to access) Google Play through any automated means (including use of scripts, crawlers, or similar technologies) and shall ensure that you comply with the instructions set out in any robots.txt file present on the Google Play website.

However [This](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-market-api/) is an unofficial open source API for the android market.